# API binance P2P solo accedo a una parte (solo el BUY) y no a todo (BUY y SELL)

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

Estoy intentando acceder a los datos de esta pagina de Binance. Es el P2P: https://p2p.binance.com/en/trade/buy/USDT.

Para la compra (BUY) estoy usando esto en python3:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "123",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "Host": "p2p.binance.com",
    "Origin": "https://p2p.binance.com",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "TE": "Trailers",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
}

data = {
  "asset": "USDT",
  "fiat": "ARS",
  "merchantCheck": False,
  "page": 1,
  "payTypes": [],
  "publisherType": None,
  "rows": 50,
  "tradeType": "BUY"
}


r = requests.post('https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search', headers=headers, json=data)
print(r.text)
```

Pero después cuando quiero acceder a esta parte de la pagina: https://p2p.binance.com/en/trade/sell/USDT (al SELL), no puedo hacerlo. Porque al cambiarle en el data lo siguiente: `"tradeType": "SELL"`, me sigue trayendo los mismos valores del BUY. **Nunca me trae los datos del SELL**.

Y no estoy encontrando porqué todavía.

Answer (score 0):

Misma solución pero en NodeJS

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "123",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "Host": "p2p.binance.com",
    "Origin": "https://p2p.binance.com",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "TE": "Trailers",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
};

const data = {
    asset: 'USDT',
    tradeType: 'SELL',
    fiat: 'ARS',
    transAmount: 0,
    order: '',
    page: 1,
    rows: 10,
    filterType: 'all'
};
(async () => {
    const responseData = await fetch(
        'https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search',
        {
            headers,
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        }
    );

    if (!responseData.ok)
        throw 'bad response';

    const jsonData = await responseData.json();


    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData, 0, 4));

})()
```